# How to search Android Applications by size?

Tags: google-play-store, search, amazon-appstore, app-brain

Is there any way I can search or filter android apps by size less than 1MB or 2MB on any android app store? I have a low end android phone with less memory and installation space.

Light weight apps are mostly faster and I can install more of them therefore I want to search small apps only.